# Code to convert in Cake Php

Tags: cakephp

I want this code to write with CakePhp convention Please Help
This is my core php code.There are 3 steps through which form process goes.
In step 1 details of clients and form is redirected to  step 2  here one add the products and then data is saved to invoices and Product table.
Not all code but if some clue is provided how to proceed it in actions get $steps and do operations on it

This is add.php

```
<?
include "inc/functions.php";

if(!$_SESSION['logged']){
header("Location: login/");
}
$meniu='add';
$step=1;
    if(isset($_GET['step'])){
        $step=$_GET['step'];
    }

    if(isset($_POST['step1'])){
    if($_POST['client_name']==''){
        $err['client_name']='error';
    }else{
        $_SESSION['order']['client_name']=$_POST['client_name'];
        $_SESSION['order']['client_email']=$_POST['client_email'];
        $_SESSION['order']['client_phone']=$_POST['client_phone'];
        $_SESSION['order']['client_address']=$_POST['client_address'];
        $_SESSION['order']['client_location']=$_POST['client_location'];
        $_SESSION['order']['payment_method']=$_POST['payment_method'];
        header("Location: add.php?step=2");
    }
    }       

    if(isset($_POST['step2'])){
        mysql_query("insert into       invoices(client_name,client_email,client_phone,client_address,client_location,payment_metho    d,vat,total,currency,date) values('".$_SESSION['order']    ['client_name']."','".$_SESSION['order']['client_email']."','".$_SESSION['order']['client_phone']."','".$_SESSION['order']['client_address']."','".$_SESSION['order']['client_location']."','".$_SESSION['order']['payment_method']."','".$cfg['vat']."','".$_SESSION['total_order']."','".$cfg['currency']."','".time()."')")or die(mysql_error()."1");
            $id=mysql_insert_id();

        foreach($_SESSION['products'] as $tag=>$val){
            mysql_query("insert into products(title,description,qty,price,taxes,invoice) values('".$val['title']."','".$val['description']."','".$val['qty']."','".$val['price']."','".$val['taxes']."','".$id."')")or die(mysql_error()."2");
        }

        unset($_SESSION['products'],$_SESSION['order']);
        $_SESSION['invoice']=$id;
        header("Location: add.php?step=3");
    }
?>
<body>
<div id='container'>
  <? include "inc/header.php"?>
  <div class='title'>New Invoice</div>
  <div id='step'>
<table align='center'>
  <tr>
    <td class='step <? if($step==1){?>current<? }elseif($step>1){?>done<? }?>'>Setup Client</td>
    <td class='step <? if($step==2){?>current<? }elseif($step>2){?>done<? }?>'>Add Products</td>
    <td class='step <? if($step==3){?>current<? }elseif($step>3){?>done<? }?>'>Save/Export</td>
  </tr>
</table>
  </div>
  <div id='content'>
    <?
        if($step==1){include "inc/step1.php";}
        if($step==2){include "inc/step2.php";}
        if($step==3){include "inc/step3.php";}
        ?>
  </div>
    </div>
    <? include "inc/footer.php"?>
   </body>
```

Comment: You should first learn the principles of MVC that CakePHP uses. You'll then be able to split your code in MVC style and by reading CakePHP's docs, you'll be able to play with sessions, redirects, forms, errors, saves and so on. We cannot help you since you have no knowledge on these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an `Invoice` model who will be associated to your `invoices` table, a `Invoices` controller with an `add` method which will link to your `Invoice` model to save the data on your database, and an `Invoices/add` view which will have the form for adding the invoice.

The login part is very simple and it's done almost magically.

For better understanding, please do the blog tutorial; you will understand the core part of CakePHP: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started.html#blog-tutorial